# Store perl regex capture groups in bash variables

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I'm writing a small bash script to get the status of certain hardware through our api.

```
curl -sG ip:port/device/status -o temp.txt
```

I use a curl command to get the status and write to a temp file

I played around with different regex types, the simple bash regex was not enough and ended up using perl.

```
perl -nle 'printf("'%-15s' \t '%-15s' \t '%-15s' \t '%-15s' \n", "$1", "$2", "$3", "$4") while m{regex_to_capture_data}g' temp.txt
```

My regex capture is working and prints out perfectly (some of the iterations will have blank capture groups, which is important info, and that prints as expected)

is there a way to have arrays populate with those capture groups and use them further in my bash script?

say for instance $1, $2, $3, $4 were fields device_id, uptime, status, last_error. and in my curl command I have info of 4 devices. I would like to have device_id[0] up to [device_id[3], and the same for each capture group.

I'm not experienced with perl, and only used it as suggested by a few forum posts, so any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you just wrap the whole perl command you have in your post like this: `bash_var=$( perl command )` ?

Comment: Everything you do in bash can be done in perl, why switch languages?  Or show what you have tried in bash, and we can help on this.  Tools such as https://regex101.com/ can help as well.  Worst case, if you must, the perl command could be executed with `$(perl ...)` and the output added to bash variables.  Please take the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @mattb that would put the entire output of all devices in one variable

Comment: @Nic3500 thanks, I do use regex101, the issue I had was my regex I created in regex101 didn't work in bash regex as I used lazy matches which isn't supported, so used perl as a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example code is obviously broken; you can't nest single quotes; though Perl provides the convenience operator `q()` so you can easily work around this. The formatting has other errors, too. Probably you mean something like

```bash
perl -nle 'print(join("\t", "$1", "$2", "$3", "$4"), "\n") while m{regex_to_capture_data}g' temp.txt
```

You can pipe this to

```bash
while IFS=$'\t' read -r boulders rubble stones rocks; do
    ...
```

though probably you could just run the body of whatever that loop was doing from Perl directly, too.

```bash
perl -nle 'system("geologee", "--boulders", $1, "--rubbleUrl", "$2:$3/$4") while m{regex_to_capture_data}g' temp.txt
```

Comment: Hmmm thats strange, because that code worked perfectly on my mac and linux machine, no formatting errors whatsoever, but your print join command looks much neater and helped me with the next step.

Your while IFS is exactly what I wanted!! Thanks a lot! I tried something similar, but didn't pipe the command in the process substitution < <(command).

Comment: The code weirdly works, but not because it's correct.  You are interpolating literal space, backslash, t, space between the single-quoted strings and Perl is lenient enough that it lets you do that.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the advice. Everything is working now with your help, thanks a lot :D

Comment: Just a follow up question, if you dont mind me asking. I have that perl expression piped into a while loop like you showed. If say for example I have one entry that only has $1 and $4, currently it assigns $1 to "boulders" and $4 to "rubble", while it is important for me to know that "rubble" and "stones" are empty, and have $4 assigned to rocks. Would you know how to achieve this in the current setup?

Comment: Maybe you could reorder the fields so that the possibly undefined one(s) always come last? Or use a different delimiter if you can (see https://ideone.com/HnqoeZ). Or maybe output a specific placeholder value like `-` or `null` and replace it inside the loop, like `"${rubble#null}"`. Ultimately maybe running something from inside Perl with `system` might be the most sustainable solution if you need it to be completely general.